# Google play services 6.1.11 (....-012) are crashing when trying to open leaderboard on android 2.3.5 and 2.3.6

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-2.3-gingerbread, leaderboard

While testing my latest android game on 2.3.5 the leader boards (using Google play services) kept crashing although I used previously tested code in other games. So I tried out apps from the play store, and noticed that all apps are crashing when opening the leader boards on android devices with 2.3 
Is this a bug in google play services? (I am using the API9+ version of PLay services)

Test devices:
HTC ChaCha 2.3.5
Samsung Galaxy GIO 2.3.6

Anyone has an idea? Do have have an android 2.3 device that currently has a game with play services leaderboards successfully opening?

Thank you

EDIT3:
I opened a defect for the issue since the new versions of play services did not fix it:
https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=194

feel free to star the issue

PS: you might not get crash reports in your developer console because the game continues to run it is the services/leaderboards activity that crashes

EDIT2:
Issue still present on 6.1.83 !

EDIT1:
Adding the stack below, it seems that there is a resource missing which is in the GUI of the leaderboard, and as far as I know, the developer cannot fix it in his app because the play services project will be used is the one fetched from the play services version running on the user's device right?

Stack

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.Ch
eckBox
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater
.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.common.leaderboards.o.a(SourceFile:113)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.cg.a(SourceFile:14)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.google.android.gms.games.ui.bo.a(SourceFile:18)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.cf.b(SourceFile:3204)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.au.a(SourceFile:1789)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.am.a(SourceFile:268)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:1251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(SourceFile:508)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.am.a(SourceFile:82)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.e(SourceFile:1869)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(SourceFile:2106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:536)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.google.android.play.headerlist.PlayHeaderListLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:798)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:503)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        ... 54 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/games_white_check
box.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020165
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1928):        at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(Compo
```

Comment: Do you have a bug report you can share?

Comment: I could't find the proper Google play services forums nor groups in order to book a defect or an issue. If you can point me in the right direction I'll file a report, or feel free to book it yourself. I am just waiting for the released 6.1.17 to reach those devices, hopefully with a fix for the issue. I will add the error being thrown in the main Question.

Comment: In addition adding the appcompat_v7 as additional resource for backwards compatibility does not fix the issue with 6.1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same thing started recently (Android 2.3.6). 
I think there is only Google can fix (

Comment: Thanks for your input, They have released yesterday 6.1.17 but it didn't reach my devices. And the -012 version also is not available to download on android resource ( ie android police). I'll accept your answer as long as no one can point a programer side bug.